# Removing min from LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

I want to remove 3 from this list but I am not sure where to start. I am storing a sequence of numbers in a Priority Queue that implements a linked list and trying to locate the min and remove it from the priority queue using the `removeMin` method

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Test {

    static LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        list.add(10);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(7);
        System.out.println(removeMin());
    }

    public static Integer removeMin() {
        LinkedList<Integer> pq = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Iterator it = pq.iterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            pq.add(list.remove());
        }

        int min = pq.get(0);

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            // help here
        }

        return pq.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Solution 1

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(10);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(7);
        Collections.sort(list);
        list.removeFirst();
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Solution 2:

```
 LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(12);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(7);

    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int pos=0;
    int remPos=0;
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Integer element = iterator.next();
        if(element<min){
            min=element;
            remPos=pos;
        }
        pos++;
    }

    list.remove(remPos);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I would definitely not try to sort a LinkedList with O(n) random access time.

Comment: Thanks @BladeCoder. Added one more answer which does not require sorting

Comment: Same performance problem: get(i) is a O(n) operation because LinkedList does not support direct access to elements, so if you use an index to navigate you will effectively navigate back from the beginning on each iteration. You should use an Iterator instead.

Comment: Edited answer as suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to achieve that in one line of code is using the `Collections` Class:

```
list.remove(Collections.min(list));
System.out.println(list); // to test
```

**How this work?**

- `list.remove(Object o)`: Removes the first occurrence of the specified
  element from this list, if it is present. If this list does not
  contain the element, it is unchanged.
- `Collections.min(Collection<? extends T> coll)`: Returns the minimum element of the given collection, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

---

Furthermore, if you have more than one ***min*** value in the collection you may do something like this:

```
final Integer min = Collections.min(list);
while(list.contains(min)){ // to remove all min value occurrences in list 
      list.remove(min);
}
System.out.println(list); // to test
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has some mistakes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        pq.add(list.remove());
}
```

When you are copying the list in `pq`, you are using `list.size()` but you also remove the elements of the list in the loop. So you will not copy all the elements because the `size` will be decreasing.

Also, you are not implementing a `priority queue`, is just a copy of the `list`. In order to make a `priority queue` you have to insert the element in order. Then the `min element` will be at the `top` of queue (top is the first element of the list).

When you do that, you can do a `pq.remove()` in order to remove the `min element`.